# Busybox tries to execute every command on embedded

Tags: embedded, embedded-linux, busybox

I'm using [ptxdist](http://www.ptxdist.org/software/ptxdist/index_en.html) to build uclinux for an EFM32GG DK3750. It provides a small unix shell, with busybox. When I then try to compile io.js for the distribution, and copy it to the target bin folder and run the program on the target, I get the error

```
iojs: applet not found
```

This is the same result I get from typing `busybox iojs`. Typing a random string in the shell, I get that there's no such file on the system.

Using `ls -l` in `/bin` shows that iojs is a binary, unlike the other commands provided through busybox, which are symlinks. Executing the binary directly with `./bin/iojs` results in the same error. What way can I tell busybox to not try to execute the applet, but that I want to use the binary in bin?

Comment: Read the error message carefully! That message comes from io.js, not busybox. Also: in what directory where you when typing `./bin/iojs`? `.` referes to the current directory. The absolute path would be `/bin/iojs`. I'd say io.js is not correctly installed; something is missing.

Comment: Note that the title is also missleading. You apparently have problems with jo.io, not necessarily busybox. Please consider an edit.

Comment: No matter where I try to execute iojs, the same error comes. I can do it at `/` or in `/bin`. From what I can gather, the problem is with busybox, not io.js, as the error does not make sense for me if io.js misses something. The error is also something busybox often can say ([for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19043700/busybox-in-embedded-linux-shows-applet-not-found?rq=1)), but this looks like some other error.

Comment: What I wrote about the relative path  is still true. For the error message, I correct myself. It might actually _be_ busybox then. Sorry, for that I'm out; just thought it was a simple `PATH` error (well I still think so, but I cannot help with busybox actually). One final idea: can you run any other binary (none of the busybox-links)?

Comment: I can install some other things, like ed, which is installed as binary files, and these can run. There might be something I can do with how I set up my package, but there's nothing I can understand out from any documentation that might help me.

Comment: Sorry, as I wrote; I just had some ideas, but cannot help with deeper knowledge. But if you find the answer, you really should post it here (just answer your own question; that' svery well accepted).This might help others.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the binary for io.js is really correct (right size and md5sum), and not a copy of the busybox binary. Perhaps there's a packaging problem.